# let $G$ is group,that for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$, it has exactly $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$. Then Every finite subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

let $G$ be a group having property that for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$, it has exactly $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$. Show that every finite subgroup of $G$ is cyclic.

let $H$ is subgroup of order $m$ and $H$ is not cyclic. then $x \in H$  imply $o(x)| m \ $ and $o(x )< m$ .

But then  $\sum_{d|m} \phi(d)= m$ will not longer be true, which is contradiction.

is this approach wright ?

or any better suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Your approach is right, that's a correct proof.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be true?  I don't see it.

Comment: Maybe to be clear, show why $\sum_{d|m} \phi(d)= m$ will no longer be true.